# Issue with div closing, it's href is spilling to other content

Tags: html, css

I have a site I'm making and there's a div from my nav bar that seems to be spilling out. 
If I hover anywhere but the header and footer it's as though I'm hovering over a link. Can't seem to see what the issue is.It appears to be from my login button as that's the href shown when hovering over the content but I've gone through my code and can't see an un-closed div. 
Would really appreciate some help with this one, it's wrecking my head.

Here's my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaliZorah/47nf1159/3/) Images are placeholders in lieu of my ones but are the same size approx.

```
<body>
<div class="page-wrap">

<header class="topbar topbar-grey">
    <div class="topbar-left">
        <div class="topbar-logo">
            <a href="/">
                <img class="mysite-logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-128-128-6.jpg" alt="Mysite Logo" />


            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="topbar-nav">
        <ul class="topbar-nav-main">
            <li id="home-nav"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li id="about-nav"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li id="contact-nav"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li id="gallery-nav"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li id="comissions-nav"><a href="comissions.html">Comissions</a></li>
        </ul>
   <div class="topbar-right">
   <div class="hamburger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-48-48-1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="hamburger3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-48-48-1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="hamburger2"><a href="login.html">Login</div>
    </div>
    </nav>

   </header>

    <div class="contentstuff">

     <div class="col col1">
    <div class="box1">
    <div id="box-image">

                    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
    <div id="box-image2">

                    </div>
         </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col col2">
   <div class="box2">

    <div id="slideshow-wrap">
    <input type="radio" id="button-1" name="controls" checked="checked"/>
    <label for="button-1"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-2" name="controls"/>
    <label for="button-2"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-3" name="controls"/>
    <label for="button-3"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-4" name="controls"/>
    <label for="button-4"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-5" name="controls"/>
    <label for="button-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-6" name="controls"/>
    <label for="button-6"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-7" name="controls"/>
    <label for="button-7"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-8" name="controls"/>
    <label for="button-8"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-9" name="controls"/>
    <label for="button-9"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-10" name="controls"/>
    <label for="button-10"></label>

    <div id="slideshow-inner">
        <ul>
            <li id="slide1">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" />

            </li>
            <li id="slide2">

            </li>
            <li id="slide3">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" />

            </li>
            <li id="slide4">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" />

            </li>
            <li id="slide5">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" />

            </li>
            <li id="slide6">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" />

            </li>
            <li id="slide7">

            </li>
            <li id="slide8">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" />

            </li>
            <li id="slide9">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" />

            </li>
            <li id="slide10">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-550-550-10.jpg" />

              </li>
          </ul>
       </div>
   </div>


   </div>
   <div class="box4">
   <div id="box-image3">

                    </div>
   </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

```
<footer class="site-footer">


<div class="row-1">
   <div class="logofooter">
                   <a class="logofooter" href="index.html"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-128-128-6.jpg"></a>
                   <div class="brand">
                       <a href="index.html"> MySiteLogo</a>
                   </div>
          </div>
                 <ul class="legal">
                     <li><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                     <li><a href="legal.html">Legal</a></li>
                     <li><a href="disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a></li>
                     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

            <div class="social">    

                <ul class="socicons">
                    <li><a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com"> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-64-64-10.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="twitter" href="https://www.twitter.com"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-64-64-10.jpg"> </a></li>
                    <li><a class="instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-64-64-10.jpg"> </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
       </div>
            </div>

</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try running your code through an HTML validator like [this](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). It will help you find all these "non-bugs".

Comment: Great I will do thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the `<a>` tag:

```
<div class="hamburger2"><a href="login.html">Login</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel silly. Guess I've just been staring at it so long I couldn't see it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Its not a `</div>` You are missing the closing `</a>` tag for your Login link.

```
 <div class="topbar-right">
   <div class="hamburger"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-48-48-1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="hamburger3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-48-48-1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="hamburger2"><a href="login.html">Login</div>
    </div>
```